# How to find out the cumulative count between numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i want to find the cumulative count before there is a change in value, i.e. how many rows since the last change. For illustration:

| Value | diff | #row since last change (how do I create this column?) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | na | na |
| 5 | -1 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 2 |
| 4 | -1 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 2 |
| 4 | 0 | 3 |
| 4 | 0 | 4 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 2 |
| 5 | 0 | 3 |
| 6 | 1 | 0 |
| 7 | 1 | 0 |

i tried to use cumsum but it does not reset after each change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, use a `cumcount` per group:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(df['Value'].ne(df['Value'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()
```

output:

```
    Value diff  new
0       6   na    0
1       5   -1    0
2       5    0    1
3       5    0    2
4       4   -1    0
5       4    0    1
6       4    0    2
7       4    0    3
8       4    0    4
9       5    1    0
10      5    0    1
11      5    0    2
12      5    0    3
13      6    1    0
14      7    1    0
```

If you want the NaN based on `diff`: you can `mask` the output:

```
df['new'] = (df.groupby(df['Value'].ne(df['Value'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()
               .mask(df['diff'].isna())
             )
```

output:

```
    Value  diff  new
0       6   NaN  NaN
1       5  -1.0  0.0
2       5   0.0  1.0
3       5   0.0  2.0
4       4  -1.0  0.0
5       4   0.0  1.0
6       4   0.0  2.0
7       4   0.0  3.0
8       4   0.0  4.0
9       5   1.0  0.0
10      5   0.0  1.0
11      5   0.0  2.0
12      5   0.0  3.0
13      6   1.0  0.0
14      7   1.0  0.0
```

Comment: thanks very much and also @Corralien!! will accept once I can

Comment: @parsleycoriander you're welcome, I also added a variant if you want to mask the NaN based on diff

Answer (score 1):

If performance is important count consecutive `0` values from difference column:

```
m = df['diff'].eq(0)
b = m.cumsum()
df['out'] = b.sub(b.mask(m).ffill().fillna(0)).astype(int)
print (df)
    Value  diff need  out
0       6   NaN   na    0
1       5  -1.0    0    0
2       5   0.0    1    1
3       5   0.0    2    2
4       4  -1.0    0    0
5       4   0.0    1    1
6       4   0.0    2    2
7       4   0.0    3    3
8       4   0.0    4    4
9       5   1.0    0    0
10      5   0.0    1    1
11      5   0.0    2    2
12      5   0.0    3    3
13      6   1.0    0    0
14      7   1.0    0    0
```

Comment: @mozway - meetings :(